# **Text to Columns** for binary code in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I am trying to do the Text to clumns command for columns where the cells look like this:

```
10000010011> 10101010101>01100111000> 101101010110
```

`>` is used to split the data into 4 columns.

Some data like for example this `000011001110` changes (all the first zeros are cut) turning it into this `11001110`.

Formatting as a text makes some data (011111110111000) look like this: 1,11111E+13.

Does anyone have a idea? I tried a lot of different formats.

I don't want to put a apostrophe in front of every input.

Comment: @MátéJuhász that would be same as adding `'` before every number.

Comment: @Sandeep you should try this out for yourself before making a comment

Comment: I tried this but the problem is I have to do the command Text to Columns and then formatting as a text makes some data (011111110111000) look like this: 1,11111E+13.

Comment: In integer numbers (binary, decimal, etc) the zeros at the left side have no value, so you don't need them. 000011001110  = 11001110 = 206 decimal.

Comment: @Sandeep: "that would be same as adding ' before every number." - output might be similar yes, however if you need to enter many numbers, than it's a big difference whether you need to type 100 entries manually adding `'` OR you just set all number formats at once than paste all the values at the same time

Comment: @jcbermu Its not really code, its a experiment where people had to count the zeros. I need all the numbers to create the ratio between zeros and ones.

Comment: @jcbermu: Excel can't interpret binary numbers, storing binary data as number would be a very bad practice.

Comment: @MátéJuhász checking the box text strangly still changed it to this 1,11111E+13.

Comment: it works for with your sample data. You need to select all columns and select "tex" not just for the first one.

Comment: @MátéJuhász Thanks that was the solution! Selecting all. I didn't know that that was for selecting specific colums :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting data type during "text to columns" works for me:

[image]

Note: You can set data column differently for columns, make sure to select all and set "text" for all of them.